# Jenkins - powershell output

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline step that invokes a Powershell script:

```
stage('Run script') {
    steps {
        script {
            powershell(
                returnStdout: true, 
                script: '''
                    . $env:WORKSPACE\\Script.ps1

                    Invoke-Script'''
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The `Invoke-Script` function, in turn, executes jar file inside a separate process:

```
...
$javaCommand = 'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_261\\bin\\java'
$args = @("-jar", "D:\\Test\\MyTest.jar")
$process = Start-Process $javaCommand -ArgumentList $args -NoNewWindow -PassThru
Wait-Process -InputObject $process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
...
```

The `jar` file is simple-stupid, it has just several `logger.error` lines to prove the concept. The issue is, that when I run `Invoke-Script` from `Powershell` session directly on the slave `PC`, then I see all the output in my `Powershell` console. But when I run the same code in `Jenkins`, I don't see that output in the `Jenkins` console.
Any ideas why it behaves this way and how to make my `Jenkins` to output the information into its console.

P.S. Modification of the `jar` file isn't the option, because, in reality, I can't update it (third party) and `MyTest.jar` is only for example here

Comment: Make sure the jenksins job gets to `invoke-script` by using `Write-Output` right before, then do the same thing for every step in the script to see if Jenkins read through it, that would help you narrow down the issue.

Comment: @VasilSvilenovNikolov Yes, I see all the output from the powershell script. The only output I don't see is from the `MyTest.jar` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `returnStdout: true` does the thing. Now I see both the `powershell script` and `MyTest.jar` outputs in the Jenkins console log